Make the mix-blend-mode on a sticky navbar ignore certain elements while scrolling down

My sticky navbar has a "mix-blend-mode: difference;"

When scrolling down, I would like the blend effect to interact only with the background color of the different sections it passes through.

In other words, I would like the blending effect to ignore text elements, images elements and others.

Here is an example of the issue, with the html example file:


<div class="navbar">
  <p>TEXT IN THE NAVBAR</p>
</div>

<div class="below-navbar"></div>

<div class="black-container">
  <p>An image I do not want to blend into the navbar:</p>
  <img src="https://media.4-paws.org/a/5/3/7/a537f08d227326121b80790ba54036498668c9c8/VIER%20PFOTEN_2016-07-08_011-4993x3455-1920x1329.jpg" alt="" class="img">
  <p>Some text I do not want to blend into the navbar</p>
</div>

<div class="white-container">
  <p>Some text I do not want to blend into the navbar</p>
</div>

<div class="black-container">
  <p>Some text I do not want to blend into the navbar</p>
</div>

<div class="white-container"></div>

<div class="black-container"></div>


And the css:

.navbar {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 10;  
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.below-navbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
}

.img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.black-container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.white-container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


I also did an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/08zm5w3v/4/

I have tried every kind of isolation:isolate, but my understanding is that it does not apply to componenents that are not related, and here none are related to the moving navbar.

I have tried other things, playing with stackable elements and z-indexes, but nothing worked.

I did not find any other solution browsing through forums



You will need a custom solution to create this effect. For example, I added a ::before element to each container with the same sticky value and height of the header, so every time the header goes over a container, there is a sliver of just the background color in between.
it's not the most straightforward and has some constraints but it will work.
(open in full page to make it work with the img as well)


:root {
  --navbar-height: 50px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: var(--navbar-height);
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.below-navbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
}

.img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.black-container,
.white-container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.black-container {
  --bg-color: black;
  --text-color: white;
}

.white-container {
  --bg-color: white;
  --text-color: black;
}

.black-container:before,
.white-container:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: var(--navbar-height);
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--bg-color);
  z-index: 5;
}
<div class="navbar">
  <p>TEXT IN THE NAVBAR</p>
</div>

<div class="below-navbar"></div>

<div class="black-container">
  <p>An image I do not want to blend into the navbar:</p>
  <img src="https://media.4-paws.org/a/5/3/7/a537f08d227326121b80790ba54036498668c9c8/VIER%20PFOTEN_2016-07-08_011-4993x3455-1920x1329.jpg" alt="" class="img">
  <p>Some text I do not want to blend into the navbar</p>
</div>

<div class="white-container">
  <p>Some text I do not want to blend into the navbar</p>
</div>

<div class="black-container">
  <p>Some text I do not want to blend into the navbar</p>
</div>

<div class="white-container"></div>

<div class="black-container"></div>




Brilliant, it works perfectly! Thank you very much for the answer, I would never have figured it ou by myself!

you are welcome, if you can mark it as answered thanks :]
